# Spring alert mail system for Null pointer exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, email, exception

I am looking for Spring alert mail system for Null pointer exception or any other unchecked Exception that are created in my project, so that I can have alerts of something going wrong in the app. Currently I am using spring boot. I also want Request Json to be sent in the mail, so that I can analyse if Request JSON has some data which might be creating any error.

Initially I was thinking of using `@RestControllerAdvice for @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)` & calling instance of `JavaMailSender.send()` but problem is that the method (say handleOtherException(Exception ex)) will take only Exception ex as argument & I also want incoming Request to be added in mail.

I tried adding one parameter as shown below:

```
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleOtherException(Exception ex,@RequestBody Student s1)
```

But I got below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve method parameter at index 1 in protected org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> com.example.demo.GlobalExceptionHandler.handleOtherException(java.lang.Exception,com.example.demo.Student) throws com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException: No suitable resolver for argument 1 of type 'com.example.demo.Student'
```

I have also tried looking in github but couldn't find any such thing. Please suggest any code or approach to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the concept of ExceptionWrapping in combination with the [Exception Handler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_exception_handling.htm).
Hereby you can define a lets say `ResponseException` - Object that wraps the actual exception and stores additional information like the original request or a more user specific error massage.
In the Exception-Controller you can send this wrapped exception back to the client.
The advantage is that you have only write one interface for exception handling. The wrapping is done on server-side and the client visits/handles the recieved exception based on their specific properties.

You got it almost right, there must be an additional method on server-side that generates the response object from the caught exception.
On the client site, you can for example use the Visitor-Pattern to handle the different types of exceptions.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, To add Response in ResponseException, we have to catch NPE in try catch. Since NPE is unchecked, you never know where it is going to occur, so where should I place try catch. My project is insanely big with lots of services.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a bean of Response & Autowiring it in @RestControllerAdvice

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to Panzerkroete's answer you should add your own customized ExceptionHandler 
just like below

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public CustomResponse handle(BadRequestException badRequest) {
        return getResponse(badRequest);     
    }

    public CustomResponse getResponse(Exception exception) {
        CustomResponse customResponse = new CustomResponse(exception.getMessage());
        //Call Mail Api with customResponse Object
        return customResponse;
    }
}
```

add CustomResponse class which will contain error details

add custom BadRequestException which will extends RuntimeException

now you just need to throw null pointer any other unchecked Exception(In above case throw BadRequestException) which will in turn call ExceptionHandler